# How to use group_contact in cakephp query?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-2.1

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(usertype_name SEPARATOR ','), customer_name FROM `pre`.`customer` AS `Viewcustomer` WHERE `Viewcustomer`.`customer_status` = 0 AND `Viewcustomer`.`customer_type` = 'A1'  
GROUP BY `customer_id`  DESC
```

How to write this query in cakephp?

Kindly help me to write above query in cakephp. I don't know how to write `group_contact` in cakephp query. I am using cakephp 2x

Comment: Try Google or official website of CakePHP.

Answer (score 3):

**In CakePHP 3.X**

```
$query = $this->Model->find('all');
$query->select(['field1',
                'field2' => 'group_concat(field2)',
                'field3'])
        ->group('field2');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$this->ModelName->query('SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(usertype_name SEPARATOR ','), customer_name FROM `pre`.`customer` AS `Viewcustomer` WHERE `Viewcustomer`.`customer_status` = 0 AND `Viewcustomer`.`customer_type` = 'A1'
GROUP BY `customer_id`  DESC');
```

For reference check cakephp doc http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query

Comment: I know this method .. Is it there any other option like $this->Model->find()

Comment: no there are not. you can also try this $db = $this->getDataSource();
$db->fetchAll('
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(usertype_name SEPARATOR ','), customer_name FROM `pre`.`customer` AS `Viewcustomer` WHERE `Viewcustomer`.`customer_status` = 0 AND `Viewcustomer`.`customer_type` = 'A1'
GROUP BY `customer_id`  DESC')
);

Comment: In query I renamed  GROUP_CONCAT(usertype_name SEPARATOR ',') as 'usertypename' . But in view part it is showing error .. Undefined index.

Comment: plz print and check your array. I guess 'usertypename' will be at zero index not in your array.

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me

```
$rooms = $this->Rooms->find('all', [
    'fields' =>
    [
        'roomName',
        'tiporoom_id',
        'id',
        'roomPriority'
    ],
    'contain' => 
    [
        'PhotosRooms' =>
        [   
            'sort' => 
            [
                'room_photos_priority' => 'DESC'
            ]
        ],
        'Typerooms' =>
        [
            'fields' =>
            [
                'typeName',
                'qtd_min',
                'qtd_max'
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'order' =>
    [
        'typeroom_id' => 'ASC',
        'roomPriority' => 'DESC'
    ],
    'group_concat' =>
    [
        'typeroom_id'
    ]
]);
```