# Using IFNULL ... GROUP_CONCAT() in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.5

I have a vanilla MySQL query as follows which works fine:

```
SELECT d.*, IFNULL(
     (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(value) FROM display_substances `ds` 
         WHERE `ds`.`display_id` = `d`.`id`
         AND ds.substance_id = 2 
         GROUP BY `ds`.`display_id`
     ), 'Not Listed'
) `substances` FROM displays `d`;
```

The background to this is that I have 2 tables, `displays` and `display_substances`. I want to render a table of every row in `displays` and the corresponding values in `display_substances` for a given substance ID (represented by `ds.substance_id = 2` in the query above).

Not every row in `displays` has a corresponding `display_substances` value. If this is the case it should output the words "Not Listed". This effectively means that if there is no corresponding row in `display_substances` - then there is no data for that `display.id` - therefore the data is "Not Listed" in the database for that particular row.  The query above does exactly this.

I want to be able to write my query using CakePHP's ORM syntax.

The structures for the tables are as follows.

```
mysql> DESCRIBE displays;
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| label    | varchar(255)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> DESCRIBE display_substances;
+--------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| display_id   | smallint(5) unsigned  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| substance_id | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| value        | text                  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The Table classes exist with the appropriate relationships defined.

```
// src/Model/Table/DisplaysTable.php
$this->hasMany('DisplaySubstances', [
    'foreignKey' => 'display_id'
]);

// src/Model/Table/DisplaysSubstancesTable.php
$this->belongsTo('Displays', [
   'foreignKey' => 'display_id',
   'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

So far I have this:

```
    $substance_id = 2;

    $data = 
        $DisplaySubstances->find()
        ->contain(['Displays'])
        ->where(['DisplaySubstances.substance_id' => $substance_id)
        ->select(['Displays.id', 'Displays.label', 'Displays.anchor', 'DisplaySubstances.value'])
        ->enableHydration(false)->toArray();
```

This will get me the rows in `displays` which have corresponding values in `display_substances` for substance ID 2. This effectively is everything where we have data, but doesn't include any rows which are "Not Listed".

I don't know how to write the `IFNULL...GROUP_CONCAT` part of my vanilla SQL query using Cake's ORM syntax.

I've read [How to use group_contact in cakephp query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36566779/how-to-use-group-contact-in-cakephp-query) so can see that it's possible to use `GROUP_CONCAT` in the `->select()` condition. But the linked example is a lot more simple because it doesn't use an `IFNULL` condition and the corresponding action (returning "Not Listed").

Please can someone advise how to write this in Cake's ORM syntax, if this is possible?

CakePHP version is 3.5.18

Comment: (unrelated):  Suggest:  INDEX(substance_id, display_id, value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IFNULL` and `GROUP_CONCAT` are both SQL functions, so you'd use the functions builder, which can be used to create any function call you want, its magic call handler will create a generic function call if there's no concrete implementation for the invoked method, ie `$functionsBuilder->IFNULL()` and `$functionsBuilder->GROUP_CONCAT()` will just work.

The functions builder also accepts expressions, so you can pass another query object to your `IFNULL()` call, ie the subquery in your example SQL.

```php
$subquery = $DisplaySubstances->find()
    ->select(function (\Cake\ORM\Query $query) {
        return [
            $query->func()->GROUP_CONCAT(['value' => 'identifier'])
        ];
    })
    ->where(function (\Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression $exp) use ($substance_id) {
        return [
            $exp->equalFields('DisplaySubstances.display_id', 'Displays.id'),
            'DisplaySubstances.substance_id' => $substance_id
        ];
    })
    ->group('DisplaySubstances.display_id');

$query = $Displays->find()
    ->select(function (\Cake\ORM\Query $query) use ($subquery) {
        // Before CakePHP 3.8.3 queries need to be wrapped in an additional expression
        // in order for the query builder to generate them wrapped in parentheses in SQL
        $subquery = $query->newExpr($subquery);

        return [
            'substances' => $query->func()->IFNULL([$subquery, 'Not Listed'])
        ];
    })
    ->select($Displays);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Using SQL Functions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions)**

Comment: I've only just had chance to try this. It gives an SQL error `Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT (GROUP_CONCAT(value)) FROM display_substances DisplaySubstances WHERE (Di' at line 1`. I can't spot where this error is as it looks like valid SQL.

Comment: Whole query is `SELECT (IFNULL(SELECT (GROUP_CONCAT(value)) FROM display_substances DisplaySubstances WHERE (DisplaySubstances.display_id = (Displays.id) AND DisplaySubstances.substance_id = :c0) GROUP BY DisplaySubstances.display_id , :param1)) AS `substances`, Displays.id AS `Displays__id`, Displays.name AS `Displays__name`, Displays.label AS `Displays__label`, Displays.link AS `Displays__link`, Displays.anchor AS `Displays__anchor`, Displays.group_id AS `Displays__group_id`, Displays.comment AS `Displays__comment` FROM displays Displays`

Comment: @Andy Please try to host such code snippets externally (gist for example), they're very unreadable in a comment. That being said, the subquery should be wrapped in parentheses ie `IFNULL((SELECT ...), ...)` (note the double parentheses, one for the function call, one as a wrapper). CakePHP should do that by default, maybe you're using a too old version, or you've modified the example code in a way that it would change the output (though I'm not sure how that would be possible).

Comment: @Andy Ah look, it was me who fixed it https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/13537 :P As a workaround wrapping the query in another expression should work in older versions: `$query->newExpr($subquery)`

Comment: Thanks very much @ndm. I can confirm this works on CakePHP 3.5.13